# Vue: не срабатывает v-on:click

Tags: vue.js

Не срабатывает скрипт, подключаю Vue через cdn (v 2.5.10). В чем может быть проблема?

HTML

```
<div  class="container" id="app">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <h1 class="caption">It's event time! Click on button!</h1>

        <button class="button" v-on:click="onClick">Press me</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    method: {
        onClick: function () {
            alert('Hi, it\'s me!')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: замените, пожалуйста, `method` на `methods`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам следует заменить `method` на `methods`. Подробнее вы можете прочитать в [документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9).